# AngularJs ui-router task for completion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

hey guys I have this task, and need some help here because it's challenging, can you give me some hints

> 1) Use ui-route to create at least 3 pages that share a single state for loading them. To achieve this, have state url parameters by dynamic and load views/controllers based on those parameters.
>   Create a method which can load the controller and template of each page on demand, when route changes. Make the state url option have 2 parameters with the second one optional (this can be done by using regexp on the url parameters) so that one of the pages can load additional information inside another ui-view based on that parameter.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
          .state('student',{
            url: "/student/:id",
            templateUrl: 'partials/1.html',
            controller: function ($stateParams) {
                alert(1)
            }})
            .state('studentTwo',{
            url: "/student/:id",
            templateUrl: 'partials/2.html',
            controller: function ($stateParams) {
                alert(2)
            }})
            .state('studentThree',{
            url: "/student/:id",
            templateUrl: 'partials/3.html',
            controller: function ($stateParams) {
                alert(3)
            }})
```

I already am in here, I have a clue on how a single state could be shared if a do a ng-repeat in front-end and change the url paramaters, but how can I dynamically load views and controllers based on those paramteres ?

Thank you !!

Comment: Alon why are you so mean? Perhaps he just needs few hints...

Comment: @AlonEitan, here I am already working on it, and yes you are right because i didn't provide code, so I apologize for that.

Comment: @gentos: you can go through ui-router documentation. They have the working plunkers and have documented each and every step. I am sure you can make it work yourself. It is not a very difficult thing to implement even if you are new to ui-router.

Comment: @gentos It's fine to ask question when you also provide the code and showing us what you've already tried. Now your question is fine :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for all the support, and from your help and guidence I managed to do it like  this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
          .state('student',{
            url: "/student/:id",
            templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
                return 'partials/' + $stateParams.id + '.html';
                },
            controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
              var ctrlName = $stateParams.type + "Controller";
              return ctrlName;
          }})
        }
```

I do a lot of panic :D :D

Comment: so we are giving html file dynamic according to params.id! cool

Answer (score 1):

you can not use same route for different states. I will ceate only one route like.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('student',{
        url: "/student/:id",
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            alert(1)
        }})
```

Then I will create another folder called partial and put all views there 1.html 2 n 3.

we can have conditional

```
<ng-include src="'1.html'"></ng-include>//condition1
<ng-include src="'2.html'"></ng-include>//condition2
<ng-include src="'3.html'"></ng-include>//condition3
```